# How can I delete the 5th word of every line in a file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I want to delete the 5th word of each line in a file.

The current content of the file:

```
File is not updated or and will be removed  
System will shut down f within 10 seconds  
Please save your work 55 or copy to other location  
Kindly cooperate with us D
```

Expected output:

```
File is not updated and will be removed  
System will shut down within 10 seconds  
Please save your work or copy to other location  
Kindly cooperate with us
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

How about `cut` :

```
$ cut -d' ' -f1-4,6- file.txt 
File is not updated and will be removed  
System will shut down within 10 seconds  
Please save your work or copy to other location  
Kindly cooperate with us
```

- `-d' '` sets the delimiter as space
- `-f1-4,6-` selects the first to 4th field (word), leaving the 5th one and then continue printing from 6th to the rest.

Answer (score 11):

A solution with `cut`:

```
cut -d ' ' -f1-4 -f6- FILE
```

Comment: Multiple `-f` is not supported in my `cut` (GNU) at least..

Comment: Supported in BSD cut but I like your response better than mine.

Comment: If it's GNU cut, you get the `--complement` flag to simplify things: `cut --complement -d ' ' -f5`.  Remember to redirect the output to a new file, then `mv` it over the original.

Answer (score 6):

awk: remove the 5th field

```
awk '{for (i=5; i<NF; i++) $i = $(i+1); NF--};1' file
```

If you want to save the file in-place: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16529716/7552

You could just erase the contents of the 5th field, but that leaves 2 consecutive output field separators:

```
awk '{$5 = ""};1' file
```

Comment: the caveat here is that changing any field's value in awk has the side effect of rewriting the whole "$0" with only 1 separator between each fields. should be taken into account if you wanted to keep any alignment (unless gnu awk has an option avoiding this? regular awk/nawk will recompute $0)

Comment: In both case you reformat the line with a *single* separator. If there is 2 space or space +tab in a separator, the result is a single space in place. This is hoppefully OK for most of the text.

Answer (score 4):

With POSIX sed:

```
sed -e 's/[^[:alnum:]_][[:alnum:]_][[:alnum:]_]*//4' <file
```

Comment: why limit the class to :alnum: and `_`  and not anything else then `:blank:` or `:space:` ?

Comment: @NeronLeVelu: That's depend on how you define what make a word.

Comment: @mikeserv; Nice catch! I updated my answer.

Comment: What's the `\(` capture group `\)` for?

Comment: @mikeserv: my mis-typing, I have just tried some ways to retain the delimiter.

Comment: To retain it, just don't include it: `sed 's/[_[:alnum:]]*//5'`

Answer (score 2):

[glenn](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215966/23408) offered a solution that is equivalent to

```
awk '{$5=""; print}' file
```

As he and others have pointed out, this

1. strips leading and trailing whitespace from every line,
2. compresses each string of whitespace (spaces and/or tabs)
   into a single space, and
3. leaves two spaces between the fourth and six words.

A hack to fix the third problem is

```
awk '{$5=""; print}' file | sed 's/  / /'
```

This will still leave one or more added space(s)
at the end of any line that had five or fewer words going in. 
If you can identify a word that will never appear in the input,

```
awk '{$5="unicorn"; print}' file | sed 's/ *unicorn//'
```

will handle even that (but it still leaves problems 1 and 2).

Answer (score 2):

```
 sed 's/^\(\([[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)\{4\}\)[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]*/\1/' YourFile > Output.txt
```

- posix sed based on space/tab separator (meta class [:blank:]])
- keep the following space after 5th word but removing the one before

A more robust (sed take the longest pattern possible and pattern with `*` could miss separation or word in first version) but a bit longer version

```
sed 's/^\([[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)\{4\}\[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}/\1/' YourFile > Output.txt
```

Comment: `sed 's/[^[:blank:]]*//5'`

Comment: @mikeserv, this will keep both surrounding separator, `sed 's/[[:blank:]*[^[:blank:]]*//5'` is better. Very good point. I suspected that sed take each single char as a entity but it take greatest unbreaked pattern as entity

Comment: `sed 's/[[:blank:]][^[:blank:]]*//4'` will remove the 5th field entirely.

Comment: @mikeserv Assuming there is not starting space on the line (like in the sample)

Comment: In this case, yes, I think you're right. Usually such a thing would be a *null* field and the behavior would be correct. In this case you should do as @cuonglm did and ensure you reference a word each time like `sed 's/[[:blank:]][^[:blank:]][^[:blank:]]*//4'`, or, w/ GNU/BSD/toybox `sed`s: `sed -E 's/[[:blank:]][^[:blank:]]+//4'`.

Answer (score 1):

Perl.

```
perl -ne 'print $_ =~ /^(\w+ +\w+ +\w+ +\w+ +)\w+ (.*)/,"\n"' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, assuming GNU cut:

```
cut -d' ' -f5 --complement file.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Perl > 5.10 (and successfully outputting *all* lines :0)  ):-

```
perl -nE '/^((\w+ +){4})\w+ *(.*)/; say $1.$3' file
```